# NGINX LUA REQUEST

Tags: api, nginx, lua, response

I am trying to run a rproxy, which should make a request before the client is connected to the backendserver.

This is my default:

```
  server {
    listen 80;

    location /proxy {
#        set $api_result "";
        access_by_lua_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/header.lua;
        # this service just prints out your request headers
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }


    location / {
#        set $api_result "";
#        access_by_lua_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/header.lua;
        # this service just prints out your request headers
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

}
```

Lua Code:

```
local res = ngx.location.capture('/number/', { method = ngx.HTTP_GET, args = {} });

ngx.log(ngx.ERR, res.status);
if res.body == 1 then
    PROXY PASS?
else
  ngx.exit(403);
end
```

When I connect to http://127.0.0.1:3000/number/
There is an output of 0 or 1 or 2
Based on this numbers I want to give out another proxy_pass: for nginx. How wo I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. use `ngx.exec` to open another location
2. set that location to `proxy_pass` somewhere else (and set it as `internal`)
3. optionally use nginx variables to make it more dynamic

Comment: Can you make a Codeexample?